# Opencv 2.3.0 Flann linking error (Xcode)

Tags: opencv, xcode4, linker, mach-o

I have an older system (OSX 10.6.8 with xcode 4.0) and I'm trying to get OpenCV 2.3.0 to work on it. The problem that I can't resolve is that whenever I try to use the flann library, my xcode gives me a Mach-O linker error. So far I've tried recompiling the all the libraries and building the dylib from a different source, but it hasn't helped. When I check the library in terminal, i get

```
Freddi-2:OpenCV-2.3.0 fredchen$ file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

My specific error code is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams::KDTreeIndexParams(int)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
  "cv::flann::SearchParams::SearchParams(int, float, bool)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
  "cv::FlannBasedMatcher::FlannBasedMatcher(cv::Ptr<cv::flann::IndexParams> const&, cv::Ptr<cv::flann::SearchParams> const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
  "cv::BFMatcher::BFMatcher(int, bool)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
  "cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()", referenced from:
  cv::flann::SearchParams::~SearchParams() in main.o
  "cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()", referenced from:
  cv::Ptr<cv::flann::IndexParams>::delete_obj() in main.o
  "vtable for cv::BFMatcher", referenced from:
  cv::BFMatcher::~BFMatcher() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The dynamic libraries I have linked with the project are:

```
libopencv_video.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_objdetect.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_ml.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_legacy.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_gpu.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_contrib.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_ts.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_highgui.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_flann.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_features2d.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_core.2.3.0.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.2.3.0.dylib
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar errors when I was using 2.3.0 on Mac. You should try to stick with the latest version, either 2.4.4 or the latests from github.